# Redirect loop in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an express middleware with routes defined in such a way that if a request is not authenticated is redirected to a login page that is served from static files:

```
  app.use('/login', authMiddleware.login);
  app.get(['/static', '/static*'], authMiddleware.login);
  app.use('/logout', authMiddleware.logout);
  app.use('/check-login', authMiddleware.checkLogin);
  // For any request that is not authenticated 'authenticat' 
  // would redirect  to /login
  app.use('*', authMiddleware.authenticate);
```

in the login function I check the request url and serve an html file. If the url has the `static` in the begining of the path, I want to return the file requested. So when user is unauthorized, I send her to '/login'  where index.html is presented and in it there are references to css and Js in the static directory:

```
module.exports.login = (req, resp, next) => {

  const name = req.originalUrl.split('/');
   // If the request is for /static/file.js or static/file.css then:
  if (name[1] === 'static') {
       // Send the file 
    console.dir(path.join(`${__dirname}${req.originalUrl}`));
    resp.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}${req.originalUrl}`));
  }
  if (name[1] === 'login') {     
    console.dir(path.join(`${__dirname}${req.originalUrl}`));
    resp.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/static/index.html`));
  }
  next();
};
```

And here is my `authenticate` function:

```
module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  if  (!req.session.accessToken) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    return next();
  }
};
```

This is working for the `index.html` file but not for the CSS/JS served from the static directory. The requests for the static css/js are ending up in a redirect loop. I suspect there is an issue with my login function logic and the way I am checking for the `/static` in the request or the precedence in the routes.

Comment: figured it out... it was due to my careless use of `next()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the `next()` function in login. Removing it allowed the application to work as expected.